# Checking whether the first row field equals variable

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Select Like so(Simplified)

```
Select E.User_Id 
FROM Users E
Inner Join League_Point P On E.Point_Id = P.Id
Group By E.User_Id
```

I'm creating a Points table sorted by User_Id. What I need to know is, how can you check whether the first row in a table equals a given value. For instance, checking whether the top ranked User Equals a declared value.

Comment: Could you show a small sample of tables `Users` and `League_Point` and then show a table with expected results? Please kindly clarify if this is sql-server (Microsoft SQL) or mysql (the open source one with a dolphin logo).

Comment: By definition a table is an unordered set. So the concept of the first row is not valid. Order is defined when selecting data. Your question just isn't clear as to what you want.

Comment: This query is nonsensical. Can we see the actual one?

Comment: I removed the DBMS specific tags. Feel free to add the one you are actually using.